Unknown piano double bar notation
I encountered this notation in the left hand today and have no idea what it could possibly mean. Maybe someone can explain it to me.


Future questions of that type would benefit from inclusion of a full bar or the time signature.

Hint: it's about rhythm and could be related to the time signature and length of a bar, but we can't see those things in your cropped photo.
